# Создание динамических столбцов в Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

У меня имеется таблица Balance, содержащая следующие поля:

1. дата финансовой отчетности (31.12.2022 года, 30.06.2023 года, 31.12.2023 года)
2. статьи финансовой отчетности
3. значения статей финансовой отчетности на указанные выше даты.

Далее мной построен визуальный элемент в виде матрицы, содержащий поля:

1. статьи финансовой отчетности
2. значения статей финансовой отчетности на дату 31.12.2023 года (имеются срезы по дате финансовой отчетности)

Моей задачей является добавить кнопки с датами 31.12.2022 года и 30.06.2023 года на холст, чтобы при выборе одной из дат добавлялся столбец со значениями статей финансовой отчетности на 31.12.2022 года или 30.06.2023 года.

Я пытался создать DAX формулу используя SELECTEDCOLUMNS, но видимо я неправильно пищу формулу.

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом это можно реализовать?